# what language to use to perform mcmc algorithms?

Tags: java, c++11

this is more a philosophical question. I want to start implementing MCMC algorithms in a programming language that is not matlab or R.

What would you suggest to use? C/C++ or Java?
I want after implmentetion to draw histograms etc but like those in R, matlab. Does any of the above languages have anything like "routine" to do this or after obtaining the results i can do this in matlab or R for example?

For what is worth, i don't know any of the above languages (C/C++ or Java). So i will take it from scratch.

Comment: Java is easier, but both should be able to do it just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do MCMC in Java, C, or C++, you will either need to write a lot of code yourself or look for third-party libraries. The features you are looking for are not included in the core language for any of these.

(Also note that C and C++ are very distinct languages. They have diverged a long way from their common roots more than 30 years ago -- ancient history in computer years.)

Comment: thank you Monad. I am aware of this i just wrote it this way only because of the symbols. So i guess i will start with java. Except of the third-party libraries you mentioned there is always the possibility to export the results and use matlab or r for graphics right?

Comment: @Chris Certainly there is the *possibility* that a library supports those features. However, I have no idea how high that probability is since I am unfamiliar with MCMC.